# How to make the jQuery dialog titlebar transparent

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I would like to be able to set the title bar in a jQuery dialog to transparent, I have seen the background being set to transparent but cant see anything on how to do the same to the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

Set `.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {background-color:transparent}`. You may also need to set `.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {background-color:transparent}`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt speedy ansewer I will give this a try thanks